# Gunfights in Watch Dogs after beating the game

Tags: watch-dogs

So I played and finished the story mode on Watch Dogs, and it was a wonderful experience, and I loved all the action - everything from car chases to gunfighting. Now, however, I am at a loss for how I can continue gunfighting.

After doing several Gang Hideouts, they have become exceedingly rare (Likely because they offer Skill Points, and thus are limited encounters). Now all there are are Fixer Contracts, but most of these are car chases and the like. I am looking for something similar to the story missions and gang hideouts, where you can scout out an area and then either stealth around and kill them silently, or hack their grenades to make them blow up, or environmental hazards, or get locked in an all-out gunfight and so on.

My first thought was to try and hunt the cops, which was easily achieved by shooting out a few tires on civilian vehicles (I'm Vigilante reputation - a good guy), but then I remembered that killing or even injuring cops causes you to lose reputation and become a bad guy... Thus, the fight with the cops eventually turned into a car chase. This was fun for a while, managing to get to 5 star wanted rating by switching cars as needed while the helicopter sniped me, but not what I was looking for.

Now the game is becoming dull because car chases just don't do it for me, I want to sneak around and shoot people. Is there anyway to bring back the fun the story mode presented with its various gun-and-run scenarios? Perhaps a console command to make the cop-killing no longer affect your reputation, or to reset story progress without losing your weapons/accomplishments?

Comment: Reputation doesn't really have much of an effect on the gameplay.  See: http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/170699/how-does-reputation-affect-gameplay.  The main effect is that civvies will call the cops more often.  I know you said you want to be a good guy, but I reckon cop-killing is your best way forward.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I too would like to replay the Hideout mission again!  Better yet, more new, bigger, harder hideouts.

Two ways that I've found to face off with the cops indefinitely and without lowering my vigilante status;

1. Engage the cops in an "Online Free Roam" game (either join or setup a session).  Remember though, once you endt the online game, the cops will still be searching for you.  Killing cops or citizens at this point will lower your reputation.  At this point either lose them or end the game as in point 2.
2. In your single's game, just start a battle with the cops.   The trick is, when you are finish with the battle, make sure that you either kill yourself or get kill by the cops.  The game will reload your last save.  Your stats will NOT be affected.

Do keep in mine that the game has a tendency to cheat by inserting cops behind you.

Comment: +1 for online play not affecting reputation.  The second option will only work assuming you do nothing to trigger an auto-save during your battle.  I'm not sure I'd be comfortable relying on that, as the game seems to save quite frequently.

Comment: These certainly sound like much better options; I didn't know either of these tricks!

Answer (score 6):

It might be a bit late to respond to this, but I'll leave it anyway.  I'm like you, I like to keep my reputation a bit high but like to engage in a fair bit of the ol' ultra violence now and again.  What I found worked best was to do one of the infinitely generated crimes and wait until I ran into a guy who could call reinforcements, their icon is usually a star with two curved lines next to it, like this.

((*))

Chase them for a while, don't lose them or take them out, and wait for them to call in some backup.  When they do, anywhere from two to five cars can show up with bad guys to shoot it out with.  I'd recommend bringing a lot of 'jam comms' craftables with you though, they have a tendency to shoot at you while you chase them and civvies tend to call the cops right away when that happens.

Comment: There is also the different Digital Trips, I found Conspiracy to be quite good, Spider-tank is very fun too.

Comment: I guess this is better than killing cops, but I still think that there ought to be another way, such as a command to make cop-killing no longer affect reputation... Oh well, thanks for the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Cop fights would seem to be it.

The weapon-lock-box search missions eventually unlock a bit of a bad-guy battle but it's a once off.

I've found all the slave-trade suitcases but I can't remember if that resulted in a bad-guy mission.

Hopefully, they'll patch the game at somepoint to allow mission replays... I really don't want to have to restart the campaign.

Comment: But I don't want to be a bad guy in my reputation. IS there any way to kill cops without losing reputation, or a very fast way to boost reputation after falling to bad guy status?

Answer (score 0):

I've found that being a bad guy hurts your reputation, but not that badly.  Save like 13 people, and you'll be back up. Might as well if you're getting bored. If you can, just do online free roam for that.    I too wish you could replay stuff though, especially story missions...

Comment: You currently don't have enough reputation, but in the future, you may want to post things like this as comments rather than answers.  In particular, the part about saving people seems more responsive to the original poster's comment on another answer.